# setTimeout() doesn't seem to be working in Firefox?

Tags: javascript

I have inherited a website! which was designed to work in IE and only IE it seems.. I've now been asked to make the site run in Firefox. I've fixed most of the bugs without any problems but this one has me stumped.

setTimeout(fDelayedFunc, 1000);

This line of Javascript, works fine in IE but in Firefox the function fDelayedFunc never fires. I've removed the setTimeout and the function wrapper and tried running the code as part of the main function. This works without any problems at all.

There is alot of code involved but here's the main but I'm having trouble with.  If you'd like to see anymore of the code please let me know.

```
            setTimeout(fDelayedFunc, 0);

            //Save the current text box value
            var vCurrentTBValue = vJQElement.val();

            function fDelayedFunc() {

                if (vJQElement.val() == vCurrentTBValue) {
                    alert("test");

                    //Get position list box should appear in
                    var vTop = vJQElement.position().top + 25;
                    var vLeft = vJQElement.position().left;

                    //Had to put a special case in for account due to the position co-ords being wrong. This is due to a css error
                    if (vHiddenFieldToWriteTo == "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hfAccountCode") {
                        vTop = vJQElement.position().top + 58;
                        vLeft = vJQElement.position().left + 200;
                    }
                    else {
                        vTop = vJQElement.position().top + 25;
                        vLeft = vJQElement.position().left;
                    }


                    //Create div element
                    var vDivElement = $("<div id='divSearchBox' style='position:absolute; top:" + vTop + ";left:" + vLeft + "; z-index: 40000;'></div>");

                    //Create list box
                    var vListBox = $("<select id='lbResults' tabIndex='" + vJQElement.attr("tabIndex") + "' size='4' style='height:400px;'></select>");


                    //Bind a function to the list box which will select the item via either tab or enter
                    vListBox.bind("keydown", function() {
                        //Check if tab or enter has been pressed
                        if (event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 13) {
                            //Set hidden value to the selected items code
                            $(vHiddenFieldToWriteTo).val($(vListBox.find(":selected")).val());

                            //Create postback
                            $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizNewConsignment_btnRefresh').click();
                        }
                        //Check if the up arrow has been pressed at the top of the listbox
                        else if (event.keyCode == 38 && $(vListBox.find(":selected")).val() == $(vListBox.find(":first")).val()) {
                            //Focus back on the search box
                            vElement.focus();
                        }
                    }).bind("dblclick", function() {
                        //Set hidden value to the selected items code
                        $(vHiddenFieldToWriteTo).val($(vListBox.find(":selected")).val());

                        //Create postback
                        $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizNewConsignment_btnRefresh').click();
                    });

                    //Get search field
                    var vSearchText = vJQElement.val();

                    var vDepotID = $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizNewConsignment_hfDepotID").val();
                    var vCustomerID = $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizNewConsignment_hfCustomerID").val();
                    var vCountryID = $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizNewConsignment_hfCountryID").val();
                    var vConsignee = vJQElement.attr("boolConsignee");

                    //Set a loading image in place until call completed
                    vJQElement.css("backgroundImage", "url(images/small-loader.gif)");
                    vJQElement.css("backgroundRepeat", "no-repeat");
                    vJQElement.css("backgroundPosition", "right");





                    //Make AJAX call
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "NewConsignment.asmx/fGetAddressesAndIDs",
                        data: "{'strSearchText' : '" + vSearchText + "', 'intDepotID' : '" + vDepotID + "', 'intCustomerID' : '" + vCustomerID + "', 'intCountryID' : '" + vCountryID + "', 'boolConsignee' : '" + vConsignee + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function fGetAddressesAndIDsResult(GetAddressesAndIDsResult) {
                            //Make sure there are results
                            if (GetAddressesAndIDsResult != null && GetAddressesAndIDsResult != "") {
                                var vNumberOfResults = 0;
                                var vNumberOfLearntAddresses = 0;
                                var vLearntAddressUniqueID = "";

                                //Try to get results (first call will work on Linux and catch will work on Windows)
                                try {
                                    //Check array exists (if this fails will go to catch)
                                    if (GetAddressesAndIDsResult.d.length > 0) {
                                        //Loop through the results
                                        $.each(GetAddressesAndIDsResult.d, function() {
                                            //Check for results
                                            if (this.length > 0) {
                                                //Evaluate JSON
                                                var vAddress = eval("(" + this + ")");

                                                //Create list item
                                                var vOption = $("<option class='AddressOption' value='" + vAddress.uniqueID + "'>" + vAddress.briefDescription + "</option>");

                                                //Find out number of learnt addresses
                                                if (vAddress.uniqueID.indexOf("ConLA") != -1) {
                                                    vNumberOfLearntAddresses++;
                                                    vLearntAddressUniqueID = vAddress.uniqueID;
                                                }

                                                //Add list item to list box
                                                vListBox.append(vOption);

                                                //Mark result added
                                                vNumberOfResults++;
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (err) {
                                    //Loop through the results
                                    $.each(GetAddressesAndIDsResult, function() {
                                        //Check for results
                                        if (this.length > 0) {
                                            //Evaluate JSON
                                            var vAddress = eval("(" + this + ")");

                                            //Create list item
                                            var vOption = $("<option class='AddressOption' value='" + vAddress.uniqueID + "'>" + vAddress.briefDescription + "</option>");

                                            //Find out number of learnt addresses
                                            if (vAddress.uniqueID.indexOf("ConLA") != -1) {
                                                vNumberOfLearntAddresses++;
                                                vLearntAddressUniqueID = vAddress.uniqueID;
                                            }

                                            //Add list item to list box
                                            vListBox.append(vOption);

                                            //Mark result added
                                            vNumberOfResults++;
                                        }
                                    });
                                }

                                //Check if only 1 learnt address was found
                                if (vNumberOfLearntAddresses == 1) {
                                    //Auto select this address
                                    //Set hidden value to the selected items code
                                    $(vHiddenFieldToWriteTo).val(vLearntAddressUniqueID);

                                    //Create postback
                                    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizNewConsignment_btnRefresh').click();
                                }

                                //Add list box to div
                                vDivElement.append(vListBox);

                                //Check if any results exist in div
                                if (vNumberOfResults != 0) {
                                    //Append div to page
                                    $("body").append(vDivElement);

                                    //Auto select first item
                                    vListBox.find(".AddressOption:first").attr("selected", "true");
                                }
                            }

                            //Hide loading image
                            vJQElement.css("backgroundImage", "none");
                        },
                        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            //Inform user of error
                            alert("An error occured, please try again");

                            //Hide loading image
                            vJQElement.css("backgroundImage", "none");
                        }
                    });
                }

             }
```

Comment: Have you put `console.log()` calls in the function?  How do you *know* it doesn't work?  I assure you that `setTimeout()` definitely does work in Firefox!

Comment: Also, make sure you've installed Firebug before going any further.

Comment: Are you sure the first condition (`vJQElement.val() == vCurrentTBValue`) is met when the timered function fires?

Comment: I've installed Firebug thanks for the tip!

Comment: Pointy -I haven't got console.log()? in the function know. I put an alert at the top of the function before it does anything and it's not being fired.  I thought I might have a syntax problem with the SetTimeout() maybe?

Comment: Marcel Korpel - yes seems to work if I run it without the function wrapper and the settime out code.

Comment: Yes, you already said that; what I meant is: is that condition even true when the timer triggers? Set a breakpoint in Firebug on the first line of that function and check those global variables. And you put that alert within the if statement-block, so it won't show up if the condition isn't met.

Comment: ah I see what you mean now, thanks! I did try putting the alert before and after the If statment with the same results. I'll try the breakpoint in Firebug and see what I get. Thanks again!

Comment: I had this problem. Seemed like a Firefox bug, had to close the tab and reopen it, then window.setTimeout worked.

Comment: thanks @user1338062 it solved my problem temporarily, when setTimeout and setInterval stopped working (all js timers on the page, even when executing from console not working) until I closed tab and reopen (refreshing the page not enough!) - this is strange bug in Firefox, I don't know how my page can destroy timers of Firefox that last even refresh of the page :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() { fDelayedFunc(); }, 0);
```

Comment: This actually worked for me no idea why! but it seems to have solved the problem! thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you please explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I took `setTimeout(function () {function1();}, 1500)` out from the `addEventListener("load", () => {code})`

it worked for me inside Firefox

Answer (score -5):

try this : setTimeout('fDelayedFunc()', 0);

Comment: No, that's not really going to make any difference, plus it's not the proper way of doing things. The first argument should be a function reference, as it actually is in the code.

Comment: Don't use strings as parameter to `setTimeout` and `setInterval`; using this syntax is not recommended for the same reasons as using [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/eval#Don%27t_use_eval!).

Comment: you are wrong, this could this a correct way of doing it, please refer to :http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: W3Schools is not affiliated to the W3C and that tutorial is bad. Please read the article I linked to.

Comment: It's not really "wrong", it's just deprecated.  In this particular case, if it's not working the way it's written in the original question, it won't work with your modification.